# jQuery form builder for parsing email array into single input

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

I have the following in script in my web app which contains a lot of duplication. How can I cut down on this duplication and generally improve my code?

```
$('a#newAuthority').on("click", function() {
    var $newAuthorityContainer = $(".new-authority-container");

    var $row = $('<div />', {
        class: 'row'
    }).appendTo($newAuthorityContainer);

    var $large11 = $('<div />', {
        class: 'large-11 columns'
    }).appendTo($row);

    var $input = $('<input>', {
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: 'email@domain.com',
        class: 'authority-email'
    }).appendTo($large11);

    var $large1 = $('<div />', {
        class: 'large-1 columns'
    }).appendTo($row);

    var $removeContainer = $('<div />', {
        class: 'remove-container'
    }).appendTo($large1);

    var $remove = $('<a>', {
        href: '#',
        class: 'remove'
    }).html('<i class="fa fa-fa fa-remove"></i>').appendTo(
        $removeContainer);
    return false;
});
$('a#newMember').on("click", function() {
    var $newMemberContainer = $(".new-member-container");

    var $row = $('<div />', {
        class: 'row'
    }).appendTo($newMemberContainer);

    var $large11 = $('<div />', {
        class: 'large-11 columns'
    }).appendTo($row);

    var $input = $('<input>', {
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: 'email@domain.com',
        class: 'authority-email'
    }).appendTo($large11);

    var $large1 = $('<div />', {
        class: 'large-1 columns'
    }).appendTo($row);

    var $removeContainer = $('<div />', {
        class: 'remove-container'
    }).appendTo($large1);

    var $remove = $('<a>', {
        href: '#',
        class: 'remove'
    }).html('<i class="fa fa-fa fa-remove"></i>').appendTo(
        $removeContainer);
    return false;
});

$('input.button').on("click", function() {

    var $authorityInputs = $('.authority-email');

    var authortyEmails = [].map.call($authorityInputs, function(
        $authorityInputs) {
        return $authorityInputs.value;
    }).join(',');

    if ($('body.teamsnew').length) {
        $('input#team_authority_emails').val(authortyEmails);
    }

    if ($('body.teamsedit').length) {
        $('input#team_authority_emails').val('{' + authortyEmails + '}');
    }

    var $memberInputs = $('.member-email');

    var memberEmails = [].map.call($memberInputs, function(
        $memberInputs) {
        return $memberInputs.value;
    }).join(',');

    if ($('body.teamsnew').length) {
        $('input#team_member_emails').val(memberEmails);
    }

    if ($('body.teamsedit').length) {
        $('input#team_member_emails').val('{' + memberEmails + '}');
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() { 
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the code that creates a row to a function, make it return the row created with all the elements inside of it, so that you can use it like this:

```
var $newAuthorityContainer = $(".new-authority-container");
var $row = createRow().appendTo($newAuthorityContainer);
```

And then again later:

```
var $newMemberContainer = $(".new-member-container");
var $row = createRow().appendTo($newMemberContainer);
```

Alternatively, pass in the container that you want to add the row to, for example:

```
var $newMemberContainer = $(".new-member-container");
createRow($newMemberContainer);
```

The function for this latter example:

```
function createRow($container) {
    var $row = $('<div />', {
        class: 'row'
    }).appendTo($container);

    var $large11 = $('<div />', {
        class: 'large-11 columns'
    }).appendTo($row);

    var $input = $('<input>', {
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: 'email@domain.com',
        class: 'authority-email'
    }).appendTo($large11);

    var $large1 = $('<div />', {
        class: 'large-1 columns'
    }).appendTo($row);

    var $removeContainer = $('<div />', {
        class: 'remove-container'
    }).appendTo($large1);

    var $remove = $('<a>', {
        href: '#',
        class: 'remove'
    }).html('<i class="fa fa-fa fa-remove"></i>').appendTo(
        $removeContainer);
}
```

I don't see other troubling duplication.

However, I see a bit troubling typo in the variable name `authortyEmails`. This could lead to errors, so I suggest to fix that.

Comment: Thanks @janos. Can you see any other improvements, gotchas that I could use to improve this script?

Comment: I just found a semantic error in my code. The problem with your solution (now the code has changed) is that the `var $input` class name changes. Ideally I'd like to be able to DRY out the HTML creation and append the layout with the correct class to the correct container.

Answer (score 1):

General advice on code duplication is to detect pieces of duplicated code and extract them into separate, reusable, functions.

Example:

```
 var $row = $('<div />', {
    class: 'row'
}).appendTo($newMemberContainer);
```

Create row logic can be extraced:

```
function createRow() {
  return $('<div />', {
    class: 'row'
  });
}
```

and the whole piece of code would look like:

```
createRow().appendTo($newMemberContainer);
createRow().appendTo($newAuthorityContainer);
```

Sometimes you'll probably need to parametrize the functions.
In your case if you have larger blocks, you can create functions for creating whole components.

And a bit off topic maybe, but if you do a lot of HTML creation / modification in your JS, you probably should probably consider switching to knockout / angularJS, which is much better than pure jQuery manipulations.